# React form : best pattern or library

Tags: forms, reactjs, flux

I need help, I'm using React 15.0.2 (with flux) and I need to create complex forms.

I dont know if there is some kind of library or a pattern to do this.

I've tried Winterfell and I find it very long and hard to produce just a little form.
I've also tried react-forms but he produce error when I run babel because I'm using babel 6 and react-forms using old babel 5 functions.

Any idea ?

Comment: The best one is redux-form. Try no parse your *node_modules* libraries. The library is agnostic if your are using babel or not.

Comment: Did redux-form can work without redux? Because I'm using flux in my app.

Comment: Mmmm no sorry, I thought that you was using redux. There is a *formsy-react* but nothing in compare with *redux-form*. I recently need manage complex forms without a redux layer and i used the core of redux-form and make my own layer. It's hard but works pretty well with me.

Comment: I have also chosen redux-from. This example project was helpful for me https://github.com/tb/rmwl_client/blob/master/src/containers/product/ProductForm.js

Comment: Here a form validation lib without the need for Redux: https://github.com/tkrotoff/react-form-with-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Try React-Reactive-Forms, a perfect form management library in react which is based on Angular’s reactive form.

Some of the cool features are:

- Zero dependencies
- Nested Forms
- Built in validators
- Easy manipulation of form controls dynamically.
- High performance with large forms

Medium article: https://medium.com/@kuldepsaxena155/introducing-reactive-forms-in-react-e6df0b84a1ea

Repo link: https://github.com/bietkul/react-reactive-form

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [react-form](https://github.com/react-tools/react-form) which is a great tool for dealing with forms. It's lightweight and the API is really simple but also extendible.

There are some caveat though, I wrote a Medium article about that here: https://medium.com/doctolib-engineering/treating-technical-debt-62630ee64ef7

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [powerform](https://github.com/ludbek/powerform). Its a framework agnostic package.
Its tiny, simple and very explicit.
The essential apis it provides can be composed to meet any complex form requirements one can imagine.

Checkout the the React demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/625pjy4q5w).

Answer (score 0):

**Leaf Validator**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaf-validator

Declarative solutions for

- State management
- Validation
- Backward compatibility with previous form models
- Model diffing (so you can optionally send a diff of form model changes to the server instead of the whole model)

Nested forms are naturally supported because all features of this package declaratively support form models of any shape. This is important especially for validation and backward compatibility with server APIs (for zero-downtime deployments etc).